# Why does sorting my array always make the first two index values a zero?

Tags: java, random

What I am trying to get is a random number generator that will produce five lines of 5 random numbers 1 through 70 and one more number 1 through 25 like a mega millions ticket.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class MegaMillions {
    
    public void play() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(69) + 1;
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        int megaBall = rand.nextInt(24) + 1;
        System.out.println("(" + megaBall + ")");
    }

}
```

Here is an example of what I'm getting:

```
0 0 21 21 35 (1)

0 0 16 26 32 (9)

0 0 39 39 53 (3)

0 0 22 37 51 (14)

0 0 18 18 60 (14)
```

My understanding was that Collections.shuffle should take care of any repeating integers and Arrays.sort should put in numerical order.

Comment: Also, the issue is when you sort the array on each iteration as you insert values, because each time you sort, the default value of the index is 0, your values are "sorted" to the last indices of the array, with leading 0s, and when your i increases, there are 0s you do not overwrite, but instead overwrite your own values

Comment: You'll need to learn to debug. One harder issue to find is that the `nextInt` method takes a maximum value that is *exclusive*, i.e. [0..68] if the value is 69. I don't think you need the shuffle, and you can do the sort after the for loop. Bigger problem is that you probably don't want to repeat any values; in this case you can simply check if you've generated it before... And I'd use a `SortedSet` (`TreeSet`) for that instead of an array.

Comment: The recommended way to generate random numbers w/o repeats on SO is to generate a list of numbers from x to y, Collections.shuffle the list, then you can get/subList as many numbers as you need

Comment: "Collections.shuffle should take care of any repeating integers" Collections.shuffle has nothing to do with repeating values. It shuffles whatever is in the list. It does not care about the values in any way.

Comment: check: `new Random().ints(1, 71).distinct().limit(5).toArray()`

Answer (score 3):

> `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));`

Okay, your `numbers` array is now shuffled. Immediate next line:

> `Arrays.sort(numbers);`

... and now it's sorted again. There was no point whatsoever in shuffling first if you're going to sort right after. It seems clear you misunderstand what these calls do or how your algorithm works, but exactly how you misunderstand these things isn't clear from your question.

### Why do I get two zeroes?

Because that's exactly what your algorithm does. The computer just does what you tell it to.

Let's go through an example:

1. You start with a new 5-sized array; `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
2. loop 5 times.
3. (loop1) Set the 0-index to a random number: `[50, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
4. (loop1) Shuffle the list. Irrelevant, we'll sort it afterwards.
5. (loop1) sort it: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 50]`.
6. (loop1) print the 0-index number. **This is always 0**.
7. (loop2) Set the 1-index to a random number: `[0, 45, 0, 0, 50]`.
8. (loop2) Shuffle the list. Irrelevant, we'll sort it afterwards.
9. (loop2) sort it: `[0, 0, 0, 45, 50]`.
10. (loop2) print the 1-index number. **This is always 0**.
11. (loop3) Set the 2-index to a random number: `[0, 0, 47, 45, 50]`.
12. (loop3) Shuffle the list. Irrelevant, we'll sort it afterwards.
13. (loop3) sort it: `[0, 0, 45, 47, 50]`.
14. (loop3) print the 2-index number. This prints '45'.

And so on.

It seems rather likely that you don't want to shuffle **and** you don't want to sort.

You want to just fill each slot with a random number and that is all.

If you want the 5 numbers to be sorted - just sort once, afterwards. If you want to print the numbers in sorted order, first fill the entire array and print nothing - then sort it, then loop through to print it, then add the 1-25 number as final step and print that.

Answer (score 1):

Originally you have an array like

[0,0,0,0,0]

you do `numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(69) + 1;`

and may end up with  `[21,0,0,0,0]`

then you do `Arrays.sort(numbers);`

which will change to `[0,0,0,0,21]`

next `[0,12,0,0,21]` -> `[0,0,0,12,21]`

next `[0,0,7,12,21]` -> `[0,0,7,12,21]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is... odd.

The first time through the loop, ou put the first random number in the array at index 0, shuffle the array (putting the number 'somewhere'), and then sort the array (putting the number in the last place, guaranteed because the other 4 numbers are each 0). Index 0 is 0 after this.

Then repeat with second number, which goes into index 1. Note that the zero index stays zero. Shuffle, and sort again.  The first three numbers will be zero; they have to be, because there are only 2 non-zero numbers in the array.

Now the third number. Note that index 0 and index 1 remain zero.

Etc.

Summary:  shuffling and then sorting is pointless, since the sort undoes any randomization that shuffling did.

And sorting inside the loop is pointless too, since it is moving non-zero numbers to where they can eventually be overwritten, and guaranteeing some zeroes that won't be.

Guessing that you want to print out each 'ball' as it is generated, and then print them all out in sorted order:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(69) + 1;
     System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
 }
 System.out.println();
 
 Arrays.sort(numbers);
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
 }
 System.out.println();
```

This is liable to having repeated random numbers, but dealing with that should be another question.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why does sorting my array always make the first two index values a zero? ..."*

This is because you're sorting *numbers* on each iteration.

The first and second iterations would yield a *numbers* array where elements *0* and *1* are zero.

> *"... What I am trying to get is a random number generator that will produce five lines of 5 random numbers 1 through 70 and one more number 1 through 25 like a mega millions ticket. ..."*

To get 5 unique random numbers, create a *List* of values 1 through 70, and use *[Collections#shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))*.

```java
int[] numbers = new int[6];
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int value = 1; value <= 70; value++) list.add(value);
Collections.shuffle(list);
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    numbers[index] = list.get(index);
numbers[5] = new Random().nextInt(1, 26);
```

Output

```
51 11 30 59 44 (13)
```

> *"... My understanding was that Collections.shuffle should take care of any repeating integers ..."*

No, *shuffle* just re-orders the list.
You may be thinking of a *[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)*, which will only allow unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I switched a few things around and it seems to work. In order to get the results that I had intend I simply cut the `Collections.shuffle` and `Arrays.sort` lines and pasted directly below the `for` loop. Then, beneath that, I added another `for` loop that loops five times printing `numbers[i]`.  Also the final `Collections.shuffle` wasn't necessary for the mega ball.

````java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MegaMillions megamillions = new MegaMillions();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            megamillions.play();
        }
    }
}    
class MegaMillions {
    public void play() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[5]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(69) + 1;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        int megaBall = rand.nextInt(24) + 1;
        System.out.println("(" + megaBall + ")"); 
    }
}
```
````

Comment: instead of looping the whole array to print it, you can just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));`

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the sorting of array using Arrays.sort(numbers) method.
lets suppose your values is like below

0 index loop  [10,0,0,0,0]

then you do Arrays.sort(numbers);

you will get the array like this [0,0,0,0,10]

1 index loop [0,12,0,0,10] -> [0,0,0,10,12]

2 index loop [0,0,15,10,12] -> [0,0,10,12,15]

the game begins from here right?
3 index loop [0,0,10,21,15]->[0,0,10,15,21]

when you add elements in numbers[i] this actually fills the 3 index value which after sorting becomes [0,0,10,15,21].so index 0 and 1 will become always zero while looping until loop ends.

if you increase the length of the array numbers then index with zero will also increase.